# Where to keep common data like movies etc. between users?

Tags: file-sharing

Say a PC is shared among many users and everybody keeps personal data in their home directories but say a user downloaded a movie he keeps at a location where everybody else can also enjoy it.Another user downloads some songs and also wants everybody else to listen.

Is there a standard directory for this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

The standard for filesystem layout used by (most) linuxes is [here](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html), but it doesn't map very well onto your question.

If you are providing data which will be owned by root, and so normally read-only to users `/usr/share` might be a good location. An area that would be writable by multiple users would probably be better placed in `/var`.

Commonly I would try and store such data on a separate partition however, and define an automatic mountpoint in `/etc/fstab`, eg `/mnt/data`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `/var/somefolder` with 770 permissions.

Make all the users you want to be able to access the folder a member of some common supplementary group (make one if needed).

Finnaly `chown root:groupname /var/somefolder` and you should be good to go.